# Move Input form with css to centre of body

Tags: html, css

Currently I've following output and code:

CSS:

```
label{text-align:left;
       width:150px;
       display:block;
           float:left;
           clear:right;
       font-size:18;}
```

Input in Form:

```
<form>
<label>Name:</label><input name=name autocomplete=off><br>
<label>Date of Birth:</label><input size=2 name=dd placeholder=dd> / <input size=2 name=mm placeholder=mm> / <input size=6 name=yyyy placeholder=yyyy><br>
<label>Time of Birth:</label><input name=tob placeholder="hh : mm : ss"><br>
<label>City:</label><input name=city><br>
</form>
```

Output on Screen:

[image: screen]

Now I want to move all to centre of body and hence if I use `<center>` tag for `<input>` then I get following output (Because CSS is not correct):

[image: screen2]

So, What can I do to move `<label>`(CSS)+`<input>`(Form) elements to **Center** of Body?

Comment: @Downvotter: OK/BTW I am not so good in CSS yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set a width of the parent element and apply `margin: 0 auto;` to that parent element in this case you can apply to your `form` itself. Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcfps1nz/)**.

---

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  text-align:left;
  width:150px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
  font-size:18;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label>Name:</label><input name=name autocomplete=off><br>
    <label>Date of Birth:</label><input size=2 name=dd placeholder=dd> / <input size=2 name=mm placeholder=mm> / <input size=6 name=yyyy placeholder=yyyy><br>
    <label>Time of Birth:</label><input name=tob placeholder="hh : mm : ss"><br>
    <label>City:</label><input name=city><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Done! also improve my question's title if needed.

Answer (score -2):

Use a Div before your code like that

```css
 label{text-align:left;
       width:150px;
       display:block;
           float:left;
           clear:right;
       font-size:18;}
       .outer
       {
        width: 400px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
       }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <label>Name:</label><input name=name autocomplete=off><br>
<label>Date of Birth:</label><input size=2 name=dd placeholder=dd> / <input size=2 name=mm placeholder=mm> / <input size=6 name=yyyy placeholder=yyyy><br>
<label>Time of Birth:</label><input name=tob placeholder="hh : mm : ss"><br>
<label>City:</label><input name=city><br>

</div>
```

Name:
Date of Birth: /  / 
Time of Birth:
City:

`